# How to get the autocomplition working correctly for inherited methods in PhpStorm?

Tags: autocomplete, ide, phpstorm, fluent-interface

There are two classes defined as follows:

```
class Foo
{
    private $aaa;
    public function setAaa(Aaa $aaa): self
    {
        $this->aaa = $aaa;
        return $this;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    private $bbb;
    public function setBbb(Bbb $bbb): self
    {
        $this->bbb = $bbb;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

So here "fluent" setters are used. But PhpStorm seems to ignore this and displays a warning:

```
$bar = (new Bar())
    ->setAaa(new Aaa())
    ->setAaa(new Bbb())
;
```

> Method 'setBbb' not found in ...\Foo

[image: autocomplete-for-inheritance]

**Is there a way to get the autocompletion working as expected ins such cases?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all -- fix your code sample -- make it real and not some PHP-looking chunk of text.

- `class Bar extends` -- extends what?
- what is `setAaa()` method?
- what is `setBbb()` method? Your code sample does not have it.

---

Anyway ... as for the actual question, after making all the changes so it looks like real PHP code...

Use PHPDoc and ensure that it says `@return $this`. Right now it interprets `self` in `: self` part as specific class (which is `Foo`) ... and `setPropertyBbb()` is obviously NOT available in `Foo` class. By specifying `@return $this` you make it fluent in IDE eyes.

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    private $aaa;

    /**
     * My super method
     *
     * @param Aaa $aaa
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPropertyAaa(Aaa $aaa): self
    {
        $this->aaa = $aaa;
        return $this;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo 
{
    private $bbb;
    public function setPropertyBbb(Bbb $bbb): self
    {
        $this->bbb = $bbb;
        return $this;
    }
}

$bar = (new Bar())
    ->setPropertyAaa(new Aaa())
    ->setPropertyBbb(new Bbb())
;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've corrected the question, thanks for the remarks! Yes, `@return $this` solves the problem. It would be nice to find a solution without PHPDoc for setters, but in this case, your' right, the IDE will use the defined return type, and it's `self` -- and `self` is static.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would expect IDE to treat `self` in `: self` as `$this` (which means "current or child class"). But right now it treats it as current class only (just like `@return self` is treated in PHPDoc). I cannot say why exactly it's done like that .. but it is what we have right now. If you think it's a bug .. or just want a better default interpretation -- feel free to file a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI